# What does this Laravel statement means?

Tags: laravel

What does this statement means?

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
```

I am not good at these and I'm just a beginner.
What it does?

Comment: It yields `<div class="form-group has-feedback has-error">` if it has error, `<div class="form-group has-feedback">`, if not. You need to dig into Laravel from the scratch in order to learn what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$errors` is a laravel intern collection of strings. It's mainly used to show validation errors by checking if a specific string, in your example `'username'`, exists in the collection with `->has()`.

The second thing is you're using the [tenary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) which can be used to short if-statements. By using a if-statement your code would look like this
`<div class="form-group has-feedback {{ if($errors->has('username')) { 'has-error' } else { '' } }}">`
But in this example you would use the [tenary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) because its more comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

This is `$error` collection object which is getting returns from validator.
Its show you have error some validation error for username field.

`{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : '' }}`

Above one is simple ternary condition which we are using in blade template. `condition ? 'yes' : 'no';`